# How to not get different memory addresses for elements in a Realm List?

Tags: arrays, swift, realm, memory-address

If I iterate over an array in Swift with:

```
for element in array {
    ...
}
```

and place a breakpoint inside the for statement and look at the address of the object stored as element, than I get a different address than if I let the debugger run the expression:

```
array.first
```

There is only one element in the array. So, why do I not get the same address?
Here is a screenshot of the debugger in action:

[image]

I am iterating over the attachments of a mail. When I debugged, the mail only had one attachment. The debugger also stopped in the first iteration. In my two expressions you can see, that attachment has another address than attachments.first

I don't know if that helps or matters, but Message is an object managed by Realm and so is Attachment. message.attachments is of type List.

## **EDIT:**

I investigated further and it gets more weird.
I have a class Message, which is a Realm Object and has a property List of Attachments, which are also Realm Objects.

```
import RealmSwift
class Message: Object {
    let attachments = List<Attachment>()
    ...
}
class Attachment: Object {
    ...
}
```

I debugged the point where attachments are appended. After all attachments are processed, I can ask for the first element and always get the same instance with the same memory address. Behavior is like I expect it.

When the message in later usage is passed around views, I can see, that the address of the message is the same in every view holding a reference. But if I then ask for the first attachment, I always get a different address. I even get different addresses when not moving in debug mode and just running the same expression multiple times:

[image]

This is not like I expect it.

Comment: Why do you care about the memory address at all?

Comment: Probably a new instance of the proxy is created when you access the array

Comment: @DávidPásztor Because at another place, where I also have the same attachments array used, I want to find out the index of the attachment, which returns nil because it seems to be another instance.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Can you please explain what you mean with 'proxy'?

Comment: The thing that can read directly from the underlying db

Comment: @tosi the issue most probably isn't caused by the memory address difference. The fact that Realm Lists are not simple collections like Swift's Array, that can easily cause the memory address difference. You should either edit this question to explain what you are trying to do and how it's not working along with the code you use or create a new question and delete this one since it seems what you want to achieve is quite different from what you explain in your question.

Comment: But `==` doesn't compare addresses of operands, `===` does. `==` is Realm developer defined operator, and you can override it if you need so. To compare your attachments by some data fields.

Answer (score 2):

Realm `List`s aren't Swift `Array`s. The objects in a `List` are actually wrappers around a pointer to the location of the logical object in the database, and are created anew each time an element of a `List` is retrieved.

Realm does not make *any* guarantees about whether Realm object instances sourced from our object-retrieval APIs are going to be equal on a pointer-comparison basis; any semantic guarantees we do make all have to do with the identity of the objects *within* the database itself. (A single given object in the database may be represented by many `Object` instances, each of which might be a different Swift object but all of which point to the same underlying Realm object.)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I think I understood what you wrote, but this doesn't explain to me why the comparison of two elements at the same index of a list returns false. As you can see on my screenshot I created an expression: `message.attachments.first == message.attachments.first`. The Attachment class does not overwrite the == operator by the way.

Comment: it's because the getter isn't giving you a reference to an existing Swift object, it's creating a new Swift object each time that points to whatever database object exists at that index.

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not fully understand yet, why two weeks ago everything worked as intended without the need of overwriting functions, making use of the Realm function isSameObject helped me fix my problem.

```
class Attachment: Object {

    override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
        return self.isSameObject(as: object as? Object)
    }
}
```